# SU(6) -> SU(3) branching rule

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-groups, rt.representation-theory

I read in at least one paper and in the wiki below

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_model

that the 56 symmetric irrep of SU(6) breaks down into 10^{3/2} + 8^{1/2}
irreps of SU(3)xSU(2). Here the first is 40 dimensional (10 of SU(3) x 4 of SU(2))
and the second is 16 dimensional (8 of SU(3) x 2 of SU(2)).

The problem is that this is simply not true. I checked the branching rules and this
just doesn't show up. Can someone please double check if the above decomposition is
correct or not.

Thanks.

Comment: It's always sensible to approach Wikipedia entries with some caution, but I'm not clear about what "I checked the branching rules" involved on your part.   (It might help to mention your own source for branching rules.)  Computations of this sort don't usually have intuitive outcomes and can be tricky, but Robert Bryant seems to have checked carefully enough.  


Comment: I use GAP (groups algorithms and programming) with sla package for
quick branching rules (it works with algebras...) I also have a collection of code I've written over the years that is somewhat
mature and reliable...but it's always good to check these calculations
from different angles...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You appear to have made a mistake in your calculation of the branching rules.  The answer given in the wiki is correct, but it seems that you are using the 'wrong' subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(6)$.  Perhaps you are using the subgroup isomorphic to $\mathrm{SU}(2)\times\mathrm{SU}(3)$ under which the fundamental $\mathrm{SU}(6)$-representation $\mathbb{C}^6$ breaks up as $\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}^2\oplus\mathbb{C}^3$.

In the wiki page you cite, the author is using the subgroup under which the fundamental $\mathrm{SU}(6)$-representation is still irreducible, but is a tensor product of $V$, the $2$-dimensional representation of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, and $W$, the $3$-dimensional representation of $\mathrm{SU}(3)$.  Then the statement (which is correct) is that, as $\bigl(\mathrm{SU}(2)\times\mathrm{SU}(3)\bigr)$-representations, one has
$$
\mathsf{S}^3(V\otimes W)\simeq \bigl(\mathsf{S}^3(V)\otimes \mathsf{S}^3(W)\bigr) \oplus \bigl(V\otimes (W\otimes W^*)_0\bigr).
$$
These are the two irreducible subspaces that you see in the answer.

This is a special case of the general formula for $\mathsf{S}^3(V\otimes W)$ as a sum of tensor products of representations of $\mathrm{SL}(V)$ and $\mathrm{SL}(W)$.  [One term is missing because $\Lambda^3(V)=0$, and I have used other identifications that hold because the ranks of the two factor groups are so small.]

Comment: In a pure $SU(3) \otimes SU(2)$ setting, you're right :

  $S^3(3 \otimes 2)  \cong (10 \otimes 4) \oplus (8 \otimes 2)$

or in terms of dimensions $S^3(6)=40+16$; the 6,40,and 16 are all $SU(3) \otimes SU(2)$ irreps.

Comment: But the wiki article is really in an SU(6) setting. So the "6" is  referring to an irrep of SU(6).
The subgroup I'm using is the one you identified : SU(6)-6 branches to 3 + 2 + 1. I can't think of
a $SU(3)\otimes SU(2)$ subgroup where the SU(6)-6 would remain irreducible; (is that possible?). 

So the article talks about the decomposition : 6x6x6 = 56 + 70 + 70 + 20 where all these are SU(6) reps. 
The 56 here is $S^3(6)$ and as an $SU(3) \otimes SU(2)$ module it does not decompose into 40 + 16.

Comment: @Y Macdisi: Let $V$ be the $2$-dimensional rep of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and $W$ be the $3$-dimensional rep of $\mathrm{SU}(3)$. Then $U = V\otimes W$ has dimension $6$ and is irreducible as a rep of the product $G = \mathrm{SU}(2)\times \mathrm{SU}(3)$.  Since $G$ is compact and since the top exterior power of $U = V\otimes W$ is clearly trivial as a $G$-rep, there is some $G$-invariant, definite Hermitian form on $U$. Since $G$ lies in the stabilizer of this Hermitian form and complex volume form, it follows that $G$ lies in a copy of $\mathrm{SU}(6)$ acting on $U$, and this action must be irred.

Comment: @Y Macdisi:  (continued)  Thus, you can see that it is indeed possible that $\mathrm{SU}(6)$ contains a copy of $G$ that acts irreducibly on $U\simeq \mathbb{C}^6$.  Moreover, under $G$, the vector space $\mathsf{S}(U)$ does indeed break up into a $40$-dimensional and a $16$-dimesional representation of $G$, each of which is irreducible.

Comment: Your argument looks right. I'll accept that what's happening here is that there's more than one way to embed $SU(3)\times SU(2)$ in $SU(6)$ and the branching rules are different for each. I did a quick search for a subalgebra of $A_5$ with semisimple type $A_2A_1$ that keeps the
$SU(6)$-6 irrep irreducible...so far I haven't found it. 

Comment: @Y Macdisi:  Yes, in fact, it is not hard to show that there are exactly two conjugacy classes of subgroups of $\mathrm{SU}(6)$ that are isomorphic to $\mathrm{SU}(3)\times\mathrm{SU}(2)$, and they are represented by the two that we have been discussing.  This kind of thing happens more generally:  Typically, when $p$ and $q$ are bigger than $1$, there will be more than one conjugacy class of subgroups of $\mathrm{SU}(pq)$ that are isomorphic to $\mathrm{SU}(p) \times\mathrm{SU}(q)$ or a finite quotient (if $p$ and $q$ are not relatively prime) of that product.

Comment: As it turned out the sla package can already find all such subalgebras.
It found the two we've been talking about...but it also found a third!
$L_1=A_2A_1$,$6 \to (3 \otimes 2)$,$S^3(6)\to (10\otimes 4) \oplus (8 \otimes 2)$; $L_2=A_2A_1$,$6 \to (3 \otimes 1) \oplus (1 \otimes 2) \oplus (1 \otimes 1)$; $L_3=A_2A_1$,$6 \to (3 \otimes 1) \oplus (1 \otimes 3)$.

Comment: @Y Macdisi:  You are right about the third case *at the Lie algebra level*, but the third case does not give an embedding of $\mathrm{SU}(3)\times\mathrm{SU}(2)$ into $\mathrm{SU}(6)$ because it's not injective on the $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ factor, rather, this case produces a copy of $\mathrm{SU}(3)\times\mathrm{SO}(3)$ in $\mathrm{SU}(6)$.

Comment: @Y Macdisi:  (continued)  Also, neither the second nor the third cases are maximal (connected) subgroups of $\mathrm{SU}(6)$.  Typically, when one wants to understand branching rules, one wants a list of maximal subgroups (up to conjugacy).  Then the algorithm for general 'branching' is to make the subgroup the end of a descending chain of subgroups such that each subgroup in the chain is maximal in the group preceding it.  Then one can do the branching by iteration using the branching rules for the maximal subgroups.